# Pyplot not installing with matplotlib

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, debian-based

I know that this is quite a common problem but when I installed this package I can't seem to get pyplot to be imported with matplotlib. My computer is currently running Pop os and I am using Pycharm as my IDE. When I run anything involved pyplot I get an the console prints out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/msm/PycharmProjects/Beginner/testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

I have already tried the following

1. sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib in the terminal
2. Searching for the package within Pycharm
3. Updating Python

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check you don't have a file called `matplotlib.py`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

if it isn't working try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and try it again
if it isn't working again try start terminal with administrator and add python -m to head of code

Comment: It says my requirements where fulfilled and pycharm is still failing to recognize pyplot. I ran
python3 -m pip install matplotlib and have upgraded pip

Comment: is your file named matplotlib.py?

Comment: im not in linux now but i have search. file name is matplotlib.py can create this issue

Comment: or try `python -m pip install -U matplotlib`